# Android bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView изменить background для каждого itemBackground

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view

Как можно изменить фон контейнера для каждого элемента. Один для всех можно задать в атрибутах, через файл селектор можно кастомизировать некоторые параметры, но задать каждому элементу разный цвет не получается. Так же я использую Navigation fragment, где переход осуществляется через navController.graph и нет возможности при выборе нужного item передавать кастомный цвет.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
```

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону custom view.  https://medium.com/@ademar111190/writing-a-custom-view-to-use-as-bottom-navigation-indicator-8cf63a737dab

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Мне уже привычен этот гугловский подход, когда для изменения цвета трёх кнопок в стандартном компоненте необходимо добавить 300 строк кода уровня грандмастер